# How much memory can I use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

How much elements can I keep in the "detached" state in the DOM ? Is there any limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit; A javascript program can use up all your RAM without being stopped.

Comment: wow, a computing system with "no limit" to memory use? what an amazing language, no wonders it's #1...

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have certain limitations depending on what you're doing (like very large `getImageData` and `putImageData` you may run into problems). But generally there is no limit.